# How to design python class so that i can return a value instead of address when using just the instance name without dot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a header file which describes the format of binary data stored. This file has fields like `DTYPE` for datatype, `NMEMB` for number of members, `NFILE` for number of files etc.

In python i am parsing the header and using class structure to easily access them later.

```py
class Header:
    def __init__(self,path:str):
        self.DTYPE = foo1() #parsing DTYPE, typical value: '<f8'
        self.NMEMB = foo2() #parsing NMEMB, typical value: an integer
        self.NFILE = foo3() #parsing NFILE, typical value: an integer
```

Later in other files i can use it as

```py
h = Header("\path\to\header.txt")
nfile = h.NFILE
```

The `DTYPE` has further substructures.

- The first character represents endianness or byte order (`<` for little endian, `>` for big endian and `=` for machine endian).
- The second character represent datatype (`f` for float, `i` for integer).
- The third character represent byte width (`f8` means 8-byte float or double, `f4` means 4-byte float)

So to further access them, i used another class representation.

```py
class _DTYPE:
    def __init__(self,dtype:str):     # input dtype = '<f8'
        self.rawString  = dtype       # get '<f8'
        self.endianness = dtype[0]    # get '<'
        self.character  = dtype[1]    # get 'f'
        self.bytewidth  = dtype[2]    # get '8'

class Header:
    def __init__(self,path:str):
        self.DTYPE = _DTYPE(foo1())   # foo1() returns '<f8'
        self.NMEMB = foo2()
        self.NFILE = foo3()
```

Later i use it as

```py
h = Header("\path\to\header.txt")
char  = h.DTYPE.character    # returns 'f'
width = h.DTYPE.bytewidth    # returns '8'
raw   = h.DTYPE.rawString    # returns '<f8'
```

However, for better code structure i want to get the raw string with the following syntax for user.

```
raw  = h.DTYPE   # It returns reference to object. i want to get '<f8'.
```

But python returns the address for `_DTYPE` object as expected like "<**main**._DTYPE object at 0x7f5742dcbe50>".

**QUESTION**
Is it possible to wire python class in a way that if i don't use dot notation it should give me a value and if i use dot notation it should switch to class object and give me access to further subclass members?

This is possible in other languages like `C#`. Also python does similar behaviours internally, as everything in python is an object. For example say in a string.

```py
text="Some string"
a=text
b=text.upper()
```

Here i can use just `text` to get the value it holds (not reference to/address of some `str` object) and i can also use dot notation to access members of the `str` class instanced as `text`.

Is there any magic methods for this purpose? If not is it probable that they add this feature - "Give a magic method to return something instead of class address when not using dot."

Appreciate your help. Thanks for your time :)

**EDIT 1:**
The suggested magic functions like `__str__` or `__repr__` only works for `print()` function. How to get that to a variable for further processing or what if i would like to return a integer when not using dot.

**EDIT 2:**
for clarification, I want the user to only type syntax `h.DTYPE` to get the raw string as `<f8` (first goal). Or if user wants, user can access further processed valued by using dot notation as `h.DTYPE.character` (second goal). The implementation i mentioned to use another class solved the second goal at the cost of first goal. The former syntax now returns address instead of raw text.

Comment: In your final example `text` _is_ a string object.  `a=text` hasn't made `a` some type of string literal.  In fact you can run `"Some string".upper()`.  What makes `str` objects not print out something like "<main.str object at 0xaaaaa>" is that the `str` class implements the `__repr__` method.  See the reference @buran has provided.

Comment: _Here i can use just text to get the value it holds (not reference to/address of some str object) and i can also use dot notation to access members of the str class instanced as text._ - this is not correct. All the time you work with `str` object,  not alternatively value and object

Comment: You already have it `raw   = h.DTYPE.rawString` if you want to assign the "value" of specific attribute to a name. And by the way, this "value" is just another object with its own attributes. Clearly there is some misunderstanding here

Comment: @buran I want the user to only type syntax `h.DTYPE` to get the raw string as `<f8` (first goal). Or if user wants, user can access further processed valued by using dot notation as `h.DTYPE.character` (second goal). The implementation i mentioned to use another class solved the second goal at the cost of first goal. Just the former syntax now returns address instead of raw text. Thanks.

Comment: `h.DTYPE` can be either instance of class `_DTYPE` or instance of class `str`. You cannot have it both ways. One work around is to have 2 attributes of `HEADER` class, one that expose the instance of `_DTYPE` and the other (read only property) to expose the `DTYPE.rawstring`

Comment: _The former syntax now returns address instead of raw text._ - again this is ONLY the representation when you print the custom class when you don't define `__repr__`, `__str__` methods. Stop thinking about it as being separate value/instance depending on syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to paraphrase your question. If this is not what you seek, let me know.

**Problem:**

> In some cases I would like to get an instance field value back when I reference the instance. I recognize that many time I want to get the address of the instance so I can reference members of the instance or copy it or what have you. Specifically, in certain situations, I would like:

```py
raw  = h.DTYPE
```

> To set `raw` to the value of a selected instance member `rawString`. However, it is also critical that I can still reference instance members like:

```py
raw  = h.DTYPE.rawString
```

**Solution:**

The way I would likely proceed is by overriding `__call__()`. This will allow you to do "something" if your instance variable is "called" as if were a method like:

```py
raw  = h.DTYPE()
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```py
class _Dtype:
    def __init__(self,dtype:str):     # input dtype = '<f8'
        self.rawString  = dtype       # get '<f8'
        self.endianness = dtype[0]    # get '<'
        self.character  = dtype[1]    # get 'f'
        self.bytewidth  = dtype[2]    # get '8'

    def __call__(self):
        return self.rawString

class Header:
    def __init__(self,path:str):
        self.DTYPE = _Dtype("<f8")
        self.NMEMB = "foo"
        self.NFILE = "bar"

header = Header("")
test = header.DTYPE()            ## <--- Calling your instance
test2 = header.DTYPE.rawString   ## <--- Referencing your instance
print(test, test2)
```

This will set `test` and `test2` to `"<f8"` and then print them giving you:

```
<f8 <f8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is closer to what i wanted. And now i can also get rid of parenthesis by using `@property` decorator on `__call__` magic function. I was almost convinced that this is not possible in python and now i am amazed!!! Could you please update your answer for future explorers. I will accept the answer anyway. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Ranit, if you add `@property`, you will get again instance of `_DTYPE` class, not a str. Try `print(header.Dtype)` after you add `@property`

Answer (score 1):

To get `raw` to print out as something other than `<__main__._DTYPE object at 0x...>` you just need to implement its `__repr__` and `__str__` methods.

```
>>> class _DTYPE:
...     def __init__(self, dtype):
...         self.dtype = dtype
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'I am a dtype of type {self.dtype}'
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self.__repr__()
... 
>>> raw = _DTYPE('float')
>>> raw
I am a dtype of type float
>>> raw.dtype
'float'
>>>
```

Your question contains an incorrect assumption about how the `str` objects work.  It is not that assigning the "raw" object to another variable name somehow makes the other variable not an object.  Both the initial string and the other variable you assign it to are referencing the same object.  The str method just implements `__repr__` and `__str__` so that the `str` value gets printed instead of the object type and memory location.

Comment: Not just `__repr__` but `__str__` too.  In fact I'd say `__str__` is the more important one.

Comment: @MarkRansom, quite right.  I will fix the answer.